# How do you read integer value from lucene document?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am using lucene.net and tried the following but it didn't work

```
NumericField myField = (NumericField)doc.GetFieldable("mynumber")
int val = (int)myField.NumericValue;
```

Any ideas how to read/convert to numericfield or any other alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumericFields are only used during indexing.  For document retrieval, assuming you've stored the field value, you should retrieve a text value from the index and convert it to an integer.

Modifying your code for a new example (uncompiled, but should be clear):

```
var myField = doc.GetFieldable("mynumber").StringValue();
var val = Int32.Parse(myField);
```

To ensure the numeric field has been stored, use the NumericField constructor that allows you to specify whether and how the field should be stored.